# Python: Executing other files

Tags: python, terminal

I am new to python, and I have these two python files. One of them is a terminal program, the other a hangman program. If I were to go on the terminal program and type "gm hangman.py" (I set up that command already) I want to switch to that python file. When the user is done with hangman (I programmed that too) I want it to go back to the terminal. I don't want to add the hangman file to the terminal because I want other people to be able to add their own games easily.

How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but I think you're looking for the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. In particular, something like this:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'hangman.py'])
```

As the docs explain, `check_call` will "Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete." That's exactly what you want, right?

But what's the command? That's where [`sys.executable`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) comes in: the command is the same Python interpreter that's running your "terminal program", and its argument is the Hangman program.

Comment: What exactly does this do?

Comment: @user3146876: If my explanation isn't good enough, either read the linked docs, or ask a specific question; I'm not going to write a tutorial and complete reference on every detail of how `subprocess` works.